# How to make Sure each playerid has at least 1 Primary Image if he has more than 0 images (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with the images table.  I need to make sure each player has a primary image if he has more than 1 image.  In the following example dataset, this would update either myimage.jpg or hisimage.jpg's primary to 1 and only1image.jpg's primary to 1.

```
Table:  Images

Playerid - 16
Image  - myimage.jpg
primary - 0

Playerid - 16
Image  - hisimage.jpg
primary - 0

Playerid - 17 
Image - only1image.jpg
primary - 0

Playerid - 18 
Image - jamison.jpg
primary - 1
```

Comment: Do you want to "make sure" by creating a MySQL rule that prohibits you from changing a 1 to a 0? or do you just want a way to check?

Comment: If a 1 exists for a player, then it meets current requirements and no data for that playerid should be changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming there must be a Player table?  If so, you could use the following...

*(This is in MS SQL Server syntax, but the logic should hold in MySQL.)*

```
UPDATE
  Images
SET
  Primary = 1
FROM
  Player
INNER JOIN
  Image
    ON Image.ID = (SELECT MIN(lookup.ID) FROM Image AS lookup WHERE lookup.playerID = Player.ID)
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Image AS lookup WHERE lookup.playerID = Player.ID AND lookup.Primary = 1)
```

This deliberately chooses the image with the lowest ID to set as primary.  Alter the correlated sub-query to implement different logic.

**EDIT**

A version that doesn't use the Player table, but possibly slower (It would need testing)...

```
UPDATE
  Image
SET
  Primary = 1
WHERE
  ImageID = (SELECT MIN(lookup.ID) FROM Image AS Lookup WHERE lookup.PlayerID = Image.PlayerID)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Image AS Lookup WHERE lookup.PlayerID = Image.PlayerID AND lookup.Primary = 1)
```

Comment: You're correct with player table, but your original query didn't provide me with the correct datasets.  Received a lot of values that already had primary images from the query after removing update and set with select.

Comment: The `NOT EXISTS` correlated sub-query should have dealt with that.  I've changed the initial query slighty to alias both uses of Image in the correlated sub-queries.  This shouldn't make a difference, but give it a try...

Comment: Do all of your images have unique IDs?  Or could Player 16 and Player 17 each have an Image with an ID of 1?  And what do you get from this?  `SELECT * FROM Image WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Image AS Lookup WHERE lookup.PlayerID = Image.PlayerID AND lookup.Primary = 1)`

Comment: Each player has a unique playerid, each image has a unique id, the one situation this isn't returning is when a player has only 1 image, and its primary image value = 0.

Comment: With you're query, I get results (930) - and 908 from your original update query

Comment: The query in the comment will return all images for each player that doesn't already have a primary image.  The query in the answer will only return one image for each of those players.  Therefore I'd expect the comment-query to have more results, and this tells me that both queries are doing what I expect.  This, unfortunately, means that I'm stumped as to why you're not getting expected behaviour from the query in the answer.

Comment: What's weird is that almost every single result has a primary_image value of 1 - maybe something's happening with the not exists function?

Comment: Try changing the last line to this?  `AND 0 = (SELECT SUM(lookup.Primary) FROM Image AS lookup WHERE lookup.PlayerID = Player.ID)`

Comment: Hmm... still didn't do the trick, but I used something else to solve this issue away from mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a spin off of @Dems, this just makes more sense to me

```
UPDATE Images SET `primary` = 1 WHERE Player IN (
    SELECT Player FROM (
        SELECT Player, MAX(`primary`) as max_prim FROM Images GROUP BY Player
    ) as MPrim WHERE max_prim = 0
)
```

Comment: That will set the Primary flag to 1 for all images for a player.  In the case that there are multiple images for a player, only one should ever have the Primary flag set.  (Also, as far as I know, MySQL doesn't play nicely with IN clauses?  using EXISTS may be faster for that part of your logic, I'm not sure...)

Comment: `@Dems`, you're right. I didn't consider that part of OP's criteria

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could set `primary` to be 1 by default, and create a uniqueness by `(Player,primary)` and add an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE primary=0`

Answer (score 0):

Consider a refactoring of your tables.

Have a column in your player table that points to the image row which is the primary image, like this:

```
player
---------
player_id
primary_image_id


image
---------
image_id
player_id
```

That way, a player would only have one applicable primary image.